# Django Rest Framework best way to delete an object

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

So I"M Trying to make this delete method in my drf project. i setuped the `@api_view(['DELETE'])` to the views function and setuped a form method to delete the object. but it didn't worked well. so i have to make the @api_view to post method and set the form method to post to delete the object. is there any way i can make this using delete method?.

this is my view

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def delete(request,article_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_id)
        if article.author == request.user:
            article.delete()
            return redirect('/')
    
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

this is my form method

```
 <form action="{% url 'news:delete' article.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="delete">
    </form>
```

Comment: In DRF, use the HTTP DELETE to delete an object, that's the best way IMO. You call call the API using an ajax request and thus the API will be triggered.

Comment: how to call a ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

You have to send a ajax request to the api, you can use js fetch api to do so

Add data-endpoint attribute so that you can use the endpoint of your delete api endpoint in javascript. However, you can generate the entire api endpoint with your api origin through django render context.

Add id for your form, will be helpful for js

```html
<form id="deleteForm" data-endpoint="{% url 'news:delete' article.id %}" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="delete">
</form>
```

As your django code requires the csrf token to validate the user, we will need to provide csrf-token. Csrf token is stored in cookies.

```js
<script>

const form = document.getElementById('deleteForm');

const endpoint = elem.getAttribute('data-endpoint');



// The following function taken from
// https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}


function deleteSubmit(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   let csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
// Fetch api will send a delete request to your endpoint ready to handle delete requests
   fetch(`<Your APIOrigin>/${endpoint}`, {
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken },
    credentials: 'same-origin', // If the api is in the same origin

   }).then(
     // Handle Success or failure
   )

}

form.addEventListener("submit", deleteSubmit)


</script>
```